# Requesting kubernetes service by name sometimes fails

Tags: python, kubernetes, python-requests

I have an app deployed and exposed on Kubernetes, but making a requests is inconsistent - sometimes it returns `<200>` and sometimes it's an error - either `[Errno -2] Name or service not known` or `[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`.

The request:

```py
import requests

requests.get("http://someapp:1337")
```

The error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='someapp', port=1337): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnecti
on object at 0x7eff4c274fa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Yet when I make a request using IP, it always returns `<200>`

```py
import requests
requests.get("http://10.90.34.73:1337")  # --> <200>
```

kubectl describe:

```
Name:              someapp
Namespace:         app
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=someapp
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.103.244.53
IPs:               10.103.244.53
Port:              <unset>  1337/TCP
TargetPort:        1337/TCP
Endpoints:         10.90.34.73:1337
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Not sure where to go from here since the problem is so inconsistent.
Thoughts?

Comment: Well, are your service's pods dying? How many pods are behind the service other than the one IP you've used?

Comment: There is just one pod behind the service and it's up, no errors.

The pod which is exposed is a worker, which other app (another pod) keeps checking every few seconds.

Also I checked that making request with service name takes really long time - when it fails it's ~20s, when succeeds it's ~10s with just a few instances of instant (>1s) connection.

On the other hand for now I use `{SVCNAME}_SERVICE_HOST` and `{SVCNAME}_SERVICE_PORT` env variables to construct request without service name and with IP the connection succeeds every time instantly (>1s).

Answer (score 0):

Update the protocol in service definition to http rather than tcp. Also call the service by its fqdn like

```
service-name.<namspace>.<cluster-domian>.
```

Comment: Tried calling service like this, but I didn't notice any change.

```python3
requests.get('http://someapp.app.svc.cluster.local:1337')
```

Not sure what you meant with your first sentence since you wrote "update **http** rather than **http**"

Comment: The k8s service port cannot be made "http". It can only be `/TCP` or `/UDP`

Comment: yeah I found too that K8s services only support tcp  which is underlying protocol for http.